# hangman game substituting letters

Tags: python

```
graphics=['''------------''',                 
'''------------
|         |  ''',

'''------------
|         |         
|          O''',
'''------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / |''',
'''------------
|         | 
|          O 
|         / | 
|          | ''',
'''------------
|         |
|          O 
|         / |
|          |
|         / | 
|
|            ''']

print('Welcome to Hangman! Guess the mystery word with less than 6 mistakes!')


while True:
    words=['table','chair','pencil','stapler','pen','computer','printer','cable','books','shelf']

    alphabet=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g,','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

    number=input('Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list:') 

    if number=='':
        print('Empty input!')
        continue
    elif number in alphabet:
        print('Input must be an integer!')
        continue

    number=int(number)

    if number<0 or number>9:
        print('Index is out of range!')
        continue

    elif 0<=number<10:
        break

words2=[]
words2.extend(words[number])


print('The length of the word is: ',len(words2))

i=0
j=0
x='_'*len(words2)
blankword=[]
blankword.extend(x)

while j<6 and i!=len(words2):
    print('')

    letter=input('Please enter the letter you guess: ')



    if letter in words2:
        print('The letter is in the word.')
        i=i+1

        place=words2.index(letter)
        blankword[place]=letter
        blankword2=''.join(blankword)


        if i==len(words2):
                print('You have found the mystery word. You win!')
                print('Letters matched so far:',blankword2)
                print('Goodbye!')
                break
        else:
            print('Letters matched so far: ',blankword2)
            continue     



    elif letter not in words2:
        if letter not in alphabet:
            print('You need to input a single alphabetic character!')
        elif letter not in words2:
            blankword2=''.join(blankword)
            print('The letter is not in the word.')
            print('Letters matched so far: ',blankword2)
            print(graphics[j])
            j=j+1
            if j==6:
                print('Too many incorrect guesses. You lost!')
                print('The word was:',words[number])
                print('Goodbye!')
```

Hey I made this hangman game. I just had one question. Lets say I choose 'books' as the initial
word. If I enter 'o', it only shows the first o in books and not the second. How can I get it
to show both the 'o' when the letter is entered the first time?

Thanks! :)

Comment: you need to read the word that you set as the answer, and go through each character, and do if(enteredCharacter == character you want) display all letters

Comment: Why are you looping over `letter`? It's one letter. You don't need to do `for alphabet in letter`.

Comment: @user2357112 actually, I was wondering why he used `for alphabet in letter` instead of `for letter in alphabet`. The former implies that each letter contains a whole alphabet. ;)

Comment: @ethg242 the alphabet list that you see if only for the first input. I edited the second part for better understanding.

Comment: @user2357112 you are right!

Comment: It is important to give all the information you can when you ask for help.  I would have written a loop answer if you had clarified that the first time

Comment: @PyNEwbie no worries. It was a very easy solution. i just used the index function and found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
place=words2.index(letter)
blankword[place]=letter
blankword2=''.join(blankword)
```

use:

```
places = []
try:
    while True:
        place=words2.index(letter)
        blankword[place]=letter
        blankword2=''.join(blankword)
except IndexError:
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the finditer its like .find or .replace except it finds alll instances of the "o" you are looking for.

> > > > `str1 = "test"`
> > > >
> > > > `str2 = "test test test test"`
> > > >
> > > > `[m.start() for m in re.finditer(str1, str2)]`
> > > >
> > > > `#[0, 5, 10, 15]``